# Server-side requirements for Outlook 2016's "Clutter" feature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

If I upgrade to Outlook 2016 for Windows, what are the server-side requirements to get [Clutter](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ie/article/Use-Clutter-to-sort-low-priority-messages-in-Outlook-2016-for-Windows-7b50c5db-7704-4e55-8a1b-dfc7bf1eafa0?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)?  I know that Office365 servers works with Clutter. What other servers will support it?

Or is Clutter in Outlook 2016 (unlike previous Outlook releases) able to work client-side without server-side support?

I'm asking because our work email is currently hosted on Exchange 2010. If we want to get Clutter, I'm wondering what our hosting options will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other servers (including Exchange 2013) support the Clutter yet. And it seems like Exchange 2016 will not get this feature:
https://twitter.com/julwhite/status/467367534245593089
"clutter won't make ExServer v.next unfortunately" said MS representative Julia White (GM Office Marketing).